# Form using reCaptcha. Issue on IE9 only

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, vbscript, recaptcha

I have a page with a form and I am using reCaptcha validation. Strangely enough it works on ALL borwsers except for IE9 (with compatibility mode off). **The error I am getting is that the reCaptcha keyword I had inserted is incorrect although it is inserted correctly**.

Below please find the code of the page. Can someone help please?

```
<!--#include virtual="/template/top/keyvals.asp" -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ie6"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <title>Request Information</title>

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/template-hardlinked/css/tableprop.css" type="text/css"/>
        <style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {color: #0079C1}

-->
        </style>

</head>
    <body onload = "changeVal()" > 
    <% 
IF request.Form.Count > 0 THEN
Dim recaptcha_confirm_text, VarString, objXmlHttp, ResponseString 

' Function to test the recaptcha field
Function recaptcha_confirm(privatekey,rechallenge,reresponse) 



VarString = _ 
        "privatekey=" & privatekey & _ 
        "&remoteip=" & Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") & _ 
        "&challenge=" & rechallenge & _ 
        "&response=" & reresponse 

'Test the user input
Set objXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
objXmlHttp.open "POST", "http://api-verify.recaptcha.net/verify", False 
objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
objXmlHttp.send VarString 

'Read the response
ResponseString = split(objXmlHttp.responseText, vblf) 
Set objXmlHttp = Nothing 

'Analyse the response
If ResponseString(0) = "true" then 
'They answered correctly  so set the confirmation variable to Correct
   recaptcha_confirm_text= "Correct" 
Else 
'They answered incorrectly  so leave the confirmation variable with the value from the second line of the response
   recaptcha_confirm_text = ResponseString(1) 
End If 


End Function 
'Call the Function
recaptcha_confirm privatekey,Request.Form("recaptcha_challenge_field"),Request.Form("recaptcha_response_field")

'Check response is correct and give relevant response
IF recaptcha_confirm_text = "Correct" Then
     Server.Transfer("/index.asp")
Else
    Response.write "<script>alert('Please enter the reCAPTCHA keyword correctly');</script>"
Response.AddHeader "REFRESH","1;URL=todelete.asp"
'incorrect response - put any additional text etc. that you want the user to see here before the response.end statement
Response.End
End If

Response.Write "<BR>"
Response.Write "<HR>"
Response.Write "<font face='arial' size='2'>The rest of the code for the page on a successful captcha goes here.<HR></font>" 
End If
%> 





              <h1 class="blueHeader"> TEST</h1>
              <p>
     Testing.
      </p>
        <p>



  <form method="post" action="todelete.asp"  name="DownloadForm" id="DownloadForm">

                  <input type="hidden" name="ThankURL" value="/pages/thankyou.asp" />       

          First Name <span class="style3">*</span></td>
          <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" size="25" maxlength="100"/>        

          Last Name <span class="style3">*</span>
         <input type="text" name="txtLastName" size="25" maxlength="100"/>      

          Email <span class="style3">*</span></td>
        <input type="text" name="txtEmail" size="25" maxlength="100" />     

        Company <span class="style3">*</span></td>
          <input type="text" name="txtCompany" size="25" maxlength="100" />      



        Address
        <input type="text" name="txtAddress" size="25" maxlength="100" />         

          City
        <input type="text" name="txtCity" size="25" maxlength="100" />  

Country:*

<select id="cmbCountries" name="cmbCountries"><option value="">Select</option>
<option value="">--------------------------------------------</option>
<option value="United States">United States</option>
<option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="Canada">Canada</option>
<option value="Germany">Germany</option>
<option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
<option value="Australia">Australia</option>

<option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option></select>

<span id="cmbstateca">State (Canada):*</span>

<select id="cmbStateca" name="cmbState"><option value="">Select</option>
<option value="">--------------------------------------------</option>
<option value="AB">Alberta</option>
<option value="BC">British Columbia</option>

</select> 


<span id="cmbaus">State/Territory:*</span>


<select id="cmbAus" name="cmbState"><option value="">Select</option>
<option value="">--------------------------------------------</option>
<option value="NSW">New South Wales </option>
<option value="ACT">Australian Capital Territory </option>

</select> 



  <span id="cmbcounty">County:*</span>

<select id="cmbCounty" name="cmbState"><option value="">Select</option>
<option value="">--------------------------------------------</option>
  <option value="Aberdeen City">Aberdeen City</option>

  <option value="Wrexham">Wrexham</option>
  <option value="York">York</option>
</select> 

<span id="cmbstate">State (U.S. only):</span>

<select id="cmbStateus" name="cmbState"><option value="" selected>Select</option>
<option value="">--------------------------------------------</option>
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
</select>                 

Telephone <span class="style3">*</span>
         <input type="text" name="txtPhone" size="25" maxlength="100" />
        Job Function <span class="style3">*</span>

         <select name="txtTitle" id="JobFunction">
         <option selected="selected">Select an Job Function</option>
            </option><option value="IT MGMT: Corporate IT Mgmt (CIO/CTO/VP/DIR) ">IT MGMT: Corporate IT Mgmt (CIO/CTO/VP/DIR) 
       </option><option value="IT MGMT: Departmental/Divisional IT Management ">IT MGMT: Departmental/Divisional IT Management       
    </select>       
How many people are there in your organization? <span class="style3">*</span>
<select id="rblUsers" name="rblUsers">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select number of users</option>
<option value="">------------</option>
<option value="home user">Home user</option>


Additional Comments <span class="style3">*</span>
         <textarea name="txtNotes" style="width:288px;" cols="64" rows="5" ></textarea>


Enter the reCAPTCHA words <strong> <span class="style1">*</span></strong>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var RecaptchaOptions = {
        theme : 'custom'
    };
</script>

    <div id="recaptcha_container">
    <label for="recaptcha_response_field"></label>
    <input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field" class="text" /><br /><br />
    <div id="recaptcha_image"></div>
    <p>Change the reCaptcha <a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('image');">image</a> or listen to the reCaptcha <br />
      words as  <a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('audio');">audio</a> </p>
    <input type="button" id="recaptcha_reload_btn" value="Get new words" onclick="Recaptcha.reload();" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=6LdYMMcSAAAAAKta499QQm49jJeAt4CasSpUxV_q">
</script>

<noscript>
    <iframe src="http://api.recaptcha.net/noscript?k=6LdYMMcSAAAAAKta499QQm49jJeAt4CasSpUxV_q" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge" />
</noscript>

<input type="hidden" id="MemberCountryOptInchkbox" class="hiddenf" name="MemberCountryOptIn" value="" style="width:20px;" >
<input name="MemberCountryOptIn" type="checkbox" class="show" id="MemberCountryOptInchkbox" value="" style="width:20px;" >
Yes, I would like to receive email communications 

                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="javascript:return gfiDownloadValidate();" class="button last">

  </form>       

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: have you provided utf-8 encoding to your webpage ?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>  but I don't know if its really the solution for your problem but that could be one way

Comment: Thanks for your help but did not work either :/